# Is there a way to ignore environment variable changes using google_cloud_run_service in Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using the google_cloud_run_service Terraform resource to create Google Cloud Run services.

Currently, whenever Environment Variables of a Cloud Run service are updated, Terraform sees this as a change to the infrastructure.

I want to ignore these changes, so that the environment variables don't need to be managed from Terraform, and Terraform won't update them when values, or environment variables changes, as I want Terraform to just manage the infrastructure.

I've tried a combination of using the ignore_changes block:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = 
       template.spec.containers.env[*]
```

But as the ignore_changes block cannot support dynamic blocks (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24188)

Are there any other workarounds that I can try?

Thank you,

Comment: It's not the purpose and mindset of terraform. I doubt you can do it...